# Mozilla unable to display images whereas IE does

Tags: html

Could anyone tell me why mozilla firefox unable to display the images where explorer can do? I even changed the extension with CAPs in all ways i can but not yet working. I have written a HTML file and my IE can open in the way i want but when i open my HTML file using the mozilla it is not displaying images but just leaving the image borders.

And also IE can reference to the CSS sheet path and making the changes but wheareas the mozilla its unable to link with css sheet path I have set the text color and font size in my css sheet and linked it with my html file. Its working perfect in IExplorer but not with the mozilla. I have been asking these thing How do i make a standard HTMl file that works on every browser And i got some answers from you but still I am unable to make it work .Can anyone tell me a good document to go through because no matter how i try its working on one browser and throwing the error on some other browser

```
                Im giving it as src="d:\text\image.png"
```

Comment: Could you be more specific, maybe post some of your HTML/CSS, that doesn't work?

Comment: Show us code! Show us how you are including the images. Most probably the paths to the image and CSS you are using are very Windows specific which IE can understand but other browsers can't.

Comment: There's no generic answer here which it sounds like you are fishing for.  You have to show us exactly what you are doing and then we can tell you what looks wrong with it.

Comment: Please post (at minimum) an extract from your HTML showing one of the offending `<img>` tags, and also the `<link>` tag for your styesheet. Also, can you clarify: are you trying to test these pages by opening the files from your local filesystem or are you running an actual web server or dev environment of some kind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using absolute paths with drive letters, e.g. `<img src="C:\www\images\foo.png" alt="foo">`, it will work with Internet Explorer but not with Firefox. If you include drive-letters etc. in the path, the path becomes Windows specific, something that IE can understand but other browsers may not.

To fix the problem, you should use relative paths, e.g. `<img src="images\foo.png" alt="foo">`. The path should be relative to the HTML file where this code is present.

Most often, web pages are written to be hosted on web servers. Images are usually put under an 'images' directory inside the document root (web-root), say, /images/foo.png. Now, the home page at /index.html can include this image either using a relative path: `<img src="images/foo.png" alt="foo">` or an absolute path (path from the document root): `<img src="/images/foo.png" alt="foo">`. Note the usage of forward-slash as opposed to back-slash. You should use forward-slash. Back-slash is very Windows specific and other browsers may not understand it.

The same applies for CSS or any other paths used in your HTML documents.

Comment: Yeah right Im using the path u mentioned So How do i give the path to make it work on mozilla

Comment: You should not be using the path I mentioned. The paths I have provided are merely examples. You should understand my response, think and decide the paths yourself depending on your directory structure and the location of your files.

Answer (score 1):

For me worked (for Mozilla Firefox v 26.0).

```
<img src="file///C:/User/MrBrown/www/images/foo.jpg">
```

Didn't worked:

```
<img src="C:\User\MrBrown\www\images\foo.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of specifying the path as src="d:\text\image.png"...

change the path as **src="file:///D:/text/image.png"**

if the folder name are having spaces.. then instead of spaces, write %20. or else open that image file in any of the web browser.. and copy the address from the address bar and paste that address as src path..

it will work for both Google chrome and firefox..